# Using an async await function is working with get request but not with post

Tags: html, node.js, express

Why does the following code works in the first request but not in the second?

This is working fine i can see the result clearly in my browser

```
 app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    let mres = await Utils.translateString('this is my text', "ar")
    if (mres) {
        res.send(mres)
    }
});
```

This is not working, it is returning `This site can’t be reached`

```
  app.post("/", upload.single("myFile"),async (req, res) => {

    let mres = await Utils.translateString('this is my text', "ar")
    if (mres) {
            res.send(mres)
        }
});
```

the following is the Utils.translateString function

```
const translate = require('@iamtraction/google-translate');
  function translateString(text, lang) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        translate(text, { to: lang }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            return resolve(res.text)
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            return resolve(err)
        });
    });

}
```

the code basically should run from an html page

```
    <html>
    
    <head><title>Infosysta - Translator app</title> </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Infosysta - Translator app</h2>
        <div id="dvfrm">
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm" onsubmit="submitfrm(e)">
                Key: <input type="text" id="txt_key" name="txt_key" required/><br/><br/>
                Text: <input type="text" id="txt_message" name="txt_message" required /><br/><br/>
                Json file: <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" required /><br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" onclick="submitfrm(event)"  value="Translate"  /> <br/>
                
            </form>
        </div>
       
        <label style="color:red" id="lbl"></label>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./uploader.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

uploader.js

```
async function submitfrm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dvfrm").show()
    let fles = $("#myFile")[0].files;
    if (fles.length == 0) {
        $("#lbl").html("translation file is required");
        return
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("txt_key", $("#txt_key").val());
    formData.append("txt_message", $("#txt_message").val());
    formData.append("myFile", fles[0]);

    let response = await axios.post('/', formData);

    if (response) {
        if (response.data.error) {
            $("#lbl").html(response.data.error);
            return;
        }
        $("#dvfrm").hide()
        $("#lbl").html(response.data.download);
        return;

    }

}
```

Comment: on Postman it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

It's cause youre using the `upload.single('myFile')` middleware in your express route. it consumes the data so you when you try the `req.body` to access the key and message, theres nothing left cause `upload.single` "ate" the data.

you can reorder the code so the `upload.single` is only ran after your route handler.

```
// Import the necessary modules and setup
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const app = express();
const upload = multer();

// Your translateString function goes here
// ...

// Your route for the test GET request
app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    let mres = await Utils.translateString('this is my text', "ar");
    if (mres) {
        res.send(mres);
    }
});

// Your route for the POST request with the upload middleware after the translation logic
app.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
    let mres = await Utils.translateString('this is my text', "ar");
    if (mres) {
        res.send(mres);
    }
    // Call the next middleware (upload.single()) after the translation logic
    next();
});

// Middleware for file upload (upload.single) - should be after the POST route handler
app.post("/", upload.single("myFile"), async (req, res) => {
    // Handle the file upload here...
    // You can access the uploaded file using req.file
    // For example: const uploadedFile = req.file;
});

// Start the server
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on http://localhost:3000");
});
```